# How to solve an iteration case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js

I'm using logic to check my checkboxes. The functionality allows you to check the parent checkbox and all the children are checked. You can also check or uncheck an individual checkbox. The problem is that I'm using pagination in my component, so if I check the first checkbox on page 1, the first checkbox on page 2 will also be checked. I believe this is because the markup occurs by index. How can I solve this problem?

```
import { useUsers } from '../../services/hooks/useUsers';

import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Checkbox,
  Flex,
  Heading,
  Icon,
  Table,
  Tbody,
  Td,
  Th,
  Thead,
  Tr,
  Text,
  useBreakpointValue,
  Spinner,
  Link,
  HStack,
  useDisclosure,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { Header } from '../../components/Header';
import { NotificationModal } from '../../components/NotificationModal';
import { Sidebar } from '../../components/Sidebar';

import { RiAddLine } from 'react-icons/ri';
import { CgImport } from 'react-icons/cg';
import { TbEdit } from 'react-icons/tb';
import { FaWhatsapp } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { CgNotes } from 'react-icons/cg';

import { Pagination } from '../../components/Pagination';

import NextLink from 'next/link';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { queryClient } from '../../services/queryClient';
import { api } from '../../services/api';

export default function UserList() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const { data, isLoading, isFetching, error } = useUsers(page);
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState([false]);

  const allChecked = checkedItems.every(Boolean);
  const isIndeterminate = checkedItems.some(Boolean) && !allChecked;

  async function handlePrefetchUser(userId: string) {
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery(
      ['user', userId],
      async () => {
        const response = await api.get(`users/${userId}`);

        return response.data;
      },
      {
        staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 10,
      }
    );
  }

  return (
    <Box>
      <Header />

      <Flex my="6" maxWidth={1480} mx="auto" w="94%">
        <Sidebar />

        <Box flex="1" borderRadius={8} bg="gray.800" p="8" overflow="hidden">
          <Flex mb="8" justify="space-between" align="center">
            <Heading size="lg" fontWeight="normal">
              Alunos
              {!isLoading && isFetching && (
                <Spinner size="sm" color="gray.500" ml="4" />
              )}
            </Heading>

            <HStack spacing={4}>
              <NextLink href="/users/create" passHref>
                <Button as="a" size="sm" fontSize="sm" colorScheme="orange">
                  <Icon as={RiAddLine} fontSize="20" />
                </Button>
              </NextLink>

              <NotificationModal />

              <Button
                as="a"
                size="sm"
                fontSize="sm"
                colorScheme="blue"
                cursor="pointer"
              >
                <Icon as={CgImport} fontSize="20" />
              </Button>
            </HStack>
          </Flex>

          {isLoading ? (
            <Flex justify="center" align="center">
              <Spinner />
            </Flex>
          ) : error ? (
            <Flex justify="center">
              <Text>Falha ao obter dados dos usuários.</Text>
            </Flex>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Table colorScheme="whiteAlpha" overflow="none" size="md">
                <Thead>
                  <Tr>
                    <Th px={['4', '4', '6']} color="gray.300">
                      <Checkbox
                        colorScheme="orange"
                        isChecked={allChecked}
                        isIndeterminate={isIndeterminate}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          setCheckedItems(
                            data.users.map(() => e.target.checked)
                          )
                        }
                      />
                    </Th>

                    <Th w="100%">Alunos</Th>
                    <Th>Ações</Th>
                    {/* <Th w="8"></Th> */}
                  </Tr>
                </Thead>

                <Tbody>
                  {data.users.map((user, index) => (
                    <Tr key={user.id}>
                      <Td px={['4', '4', '6']}>
                        <Checkbox
                          key={user.id}
                          isChecked={checkedItems[index]}
                          colorScheme="orange"
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            setCheckedItems([
                              ...checkedItems.slice(0, index),
                              e.target.checked,
                              ...checkedItems.slice(index + 1),
                            ])
                          }
                        />
                      </Td>

                      <Td>
                        <Box>
                          <Link
                            color="orange.400"
                            onMouseEnter={() => handlePrefetchUser(user.id)}
                          >
                            <Text fontWeight="bold" fontSize={['sm', 'md']}>
                              {user.name}
                            </Text>
                          </Link>
                        </Box>
                      </Td>

                      <Td>
                        <Box cursor="pointer">
                          <HStack spacing={6}>
                            <Icon
                              as={TbEdit}
                              color="gray.400"
                              fontSize="22"
                              _hover={{
                                color: 'white',
                              }}
                            />
                            <Icon
                              as={FaWhatsapp}
                              color="gray.400"
                              fontSize="22"
                              _hover={{
                                color: 'white',
                              }}
                            />
                            <Icon
                              as={CgNotes}
                              color="gray.400"
                              fontSize="22"
                              _hover={{
                                color: 'white',
                              }}
                            />
                          </HStack>
                        </Box>
                      </Td>
                    </Tr>
                  ))}
                </Tbody>
              </Table>

              <Pagination
                totalCountOfRegisters={data.totalCount}
                currentPage={page}
                onPageChange={setPage}
              />
            </>
          )}
        </Box>
      </Flex>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Rather than storing your checked state by index - which is not constant across pages and would break if a sort was applied - store your checked state by ID.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Can you show what it would look like in code?

Answer (score 1):

Add a key attribute with a value equal to the page number for the component which wraps your checkboxes.
So when the page number changes the checkboxes component will re-initialize.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Can you show what it would look like in code? Do you mean put key={page}?